# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state

Tags: django, websocket, tornado

I am trying to stream video. The script work fine locally but gives following error when i moved to server

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at sendMessage (https://website.com/video:67:24)
    at drawCanvas (https://website.com/video:59:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://website.com/video:63:17)
```

Here is script i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8888/websocket');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            let video = document.getElementById('video');
            let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            let draw_canvas = document.getElementById('detect-data');
            let draw_context = draw_canvas.getContext('2d');
            let image = new Image();
            if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function (stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                });
            }

            function drawCanvas() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 600, 450);
                sendMessage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            }

            document.getElementById("start-stream").addEventListener("click", function () {
                drawCanvas();
            });

            function sendMessage(message) {
                socket.send(message);
            }
            socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                
                image.onload = function () {
                console.log(e)};
            };
        })
    </script>
```

In server I changed to `var socket = new WebSocket('wss://10.0.1.232:8888/websocket');`

Here is code for websocket

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print ('new connection')
      
    def on_message(self, message):
        from sub_app.py_files.detect import get_face_detect_data
        image_data = get_face_detect_data(message)
        if not image_data:
            image_data = message
        self.write_message(image_data)
 
    def on_close(self):
        print ('connection closed')
 
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
 
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/websocket', WSHandler),
])
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print ('*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: `wss:/` can we assume you have this running on an SSL connection.

Comment: actually the django server is running on port 8000 and it is running on ssl. do i need websocket to run separately on ssl on port 8888

Comment: on the client side you don't have any function specifically notifying you when the socket is actually open, and you could have errors on connection you're not logging. try adding a callback to the onopen property as shown in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#events and log something to see if the socket is correctly opened before attempting to send data through it. maybe its a simple config error that you're not seeing.

Comment: ok, the issue is that i have not moved the traffic to ssl. we need to route traffic of both django server and tornado server via ssl